# Kubernetes with 2 ingress (nginx)

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I try to create a second ingress for my azure Kubernetes cluster (AKS). One for company internal use and one for customers.

The first controller is built by the following script:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.27.0/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml

And the service:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.27.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud-generic.yaml

The official tutorial from Nginx (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/) says that I need to use the --ingress-class flag to separate the two controllers. And when both controllers are created, I need to reference each resource which controller is used by ingress.class annotation.

#### first question

That makes sense because I can create two different ingresses with routing specifications. But do I also need to reference the controller in the Nginx-service?

#### second question

I edit the mandatory.yaml on my machine and applied it by a local YAML file. 
So I passed the --ingress-class flag to the arguments of the controller (started on mandatory.yaml line 218):

```
containers:
  - name: nginx-ingress-controller
    image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:master
    args:
      - /nginx-ingress-controller
      - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration
      - --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services
      - --udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/udp-services
      - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx
      - --annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
      - --ingress-class=nginx-external
```

When I redeploy it the mandatory.yaml with --ingress-class=nginx-internal, the existing controller will be reconfigured, but no second controller will be deployed.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the nginx service you need to provide selector and labels such that it selects your second nginx ingress controller pods.
2. You just changed existing deployment with name `nginx-ingress-controller` of the existing ingress controller. That's the reason why it reconfigured your existing ingress controller.You need to create new deployment yaml with a **different name** and add `--ingress-class` flag in the new deployment.

I would suggest to create two different namespaces and two different set of yamls for ingress controller 1 and ingress controller 2 and change the name, namespace, labels and selectors in those yamls.

Comment: I get following error: 7 leaderelection.go:367] Failed to update lock: configmaps "ingress-controller-leader-intranet-nginx-internal" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:ingress-nginx:nginx-ingress-serviceaccount" cannot update resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "ingress-nginx". What do I wrong?

Comment: There is a role with name "nginx-ingress-role". Add "ingress-controller-leader-intranet-nginx-internal" in the resourceNames section of that role.

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I understand that adding the "ingress-controller-leader-intranet-nginx-internal" resource name would give the second ingress access to update the configmap, but could you explain the root cause of this? The first ingress seems to have no problem updating its configmap.